# xCode 4.3.2 crashed on opening .xib

Tags: xcode, xib

I have an xCode Project created using xCode 3.2 or earlier (I do not remember).

While using xCode 4.2 I got a terrible xCode Internal Error alert on opening .xib There were two options: "Ignore" and "Crash". By selecting "Ignore" I kept the xCode running.

After updating to 4.3.x (currently 4.3.2) xCode just crashed on opening .xib. No any alerts, etc. Just crash.

Are there any suggestions how to fix this.

Thanks,
Nick.

Comment: The only one solution I can implement now is to create a new project with xCode 4.3.2 and move all source files and settings there.

Comment: I don’t know, but it could help Apple solve the problem if you filed a [radar/bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this issue, I had to create new Project with xCode 4.3.2 and move all source files, resources and project settings from my old one (the last was the most painful).

Now the xib issue is fixed and others issues (like bad indexing) is fixed too.

Thanks,
Nick.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to run the tutorial program from Xcode help and when I get to the part of adding the load button and starting the alternate editor in the right side view Xcode crashes every time. I have removed Xcode and reinstalled plus sent in bug reports but nothing has helped yet. I have tried this same code on another Mac with the same results. Seems Xcode 4.3.2 is not very stable on either of my Macs at this time.